# pandas: convert column with multiple datatypes to int, ignore errors

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a column with data that needs some massaging.  the column may contain strings or floats. some strings are in exponential form.  Id like to best try to format all data in this column as a whole number where possible, expanding any exponential notation to integer.  So here is an example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'code': ['1170E1', '1.17E+04', 11700.0, '24477G', '124601', 247602.0]})
df['code'] = df['code'].astype(int, errors  = 'ignore')
```

The above code does not seem to do a thing.  i know i can convert the exponential notation and decimals with simply using the int function, and i would think the above astype would do the same, but it does not.  for example, the following code work in python:

```
int(1170E1), int(1.17E+04), int(11700.0)
> (11700, 11700, 11700)
```

Any help in solving this would be appreciated.   What i'm expecting the output to look like is:

```
0    '11700'
1    '11700'
2    '11700
3    '24477G'
4    '124601'
5    '247602'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may check with `pd.to_numeric`

```
df.code = pd.to_numeric(df.code,errors='coerce').fillna(df.code)
Out[800]: 
0     11700.0
1     11700.0
2     11700.0
3      24477G
4    124601.0
5    247602.0
Name: code, dtype: object
```

Update

```
df['code'] = df['code'].astype(object)
s = pd.to_numeric(df['code'],errors='coerce')
df.loc[s.notna(),'code'] = s.dropna().astype(int)
df
Out[829]: 
     code
0   11700
1   11700
2   11700
3  24477G
4  124601
5  247602
```

Comment: Thanks! i did try this, but not with the fillNa..and consequently ended up w/ NaNs.  I just need to figure out now how to strip the decimal or convert to an int.

Comment: @mike01010 check the update

Answer (score 1):

BENY's answer should work, although you potentially leave yourself open to catching exceptions and filling that you don't want to. This will also do the integer conversion you are looking for.

```
def convert(x):
    try:
        return str(int(float(x)))
    except ValueError:
        return x

df = pd.DataFrame({'code': ['1170E1', '1.17E+04', 11700.0, '24477G', '124601', 247602.0]})
df['code'] = df['code'].apply(convert)
```

outputs

```
0     11700
1     11700
2     11700
3    24477G
4    124601
5    247602
```

where each element is a string.

I will be the first to say, I'm not proud of that triple cast.

Comment: thanks for this as well.  apply generally would be a bit more slow for larger lists, correct?

Comment: .apply is usually pretty fast. Its much faster than something like iterrows() usually. Depends if the function gets reinterpreted each time. The try/except would be my guess at what slows it down. If you are looking for performance, maybe a lambda would be faster?

Comment: Since this runs in O(n) time, it would have to be an extremely large list to be worth optimizing. I'd suggest giving it a run first, and if it is too slow, then look at optimization.